# C++ and Assembly subroutines

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm, irvine32

I need to create an assembly subroutine that takes a double word array and multiplies it by an integer. I have my main.cpp, multarray.h, and multarray.asm file below. I have to do the function both in assembly and c++ and then compare the run time of both. I am getting two errors that are pasted below above my code. Please help as I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Errors:

> Error 2   error A1010: unmatched block nesting :
>   AsmMultArray  F:\Assembly Project\Assembly
>   Project\lab8.asm  25  1   Assembly Project Error  3   error MSB3721: The
>   command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\lab8.obj" /Fl".lst" /I
>   "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Talab8.asm" exited with code 1.

Code:

```
**Main.cpp**
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "multarray.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    long arr1[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    const int multiplier = 7;
    time_t startTime, endTime;

    //Testing the C++ function

    time(&startTime);
    CMultArray(multiplier, arr1, 10);
    time(&endTime);

    cout<<"The time taken to run C++ function is: " <<long(endTime - startTime)<< " seconds.";

    //Testing the assembly language procedure
    time(&startTime);
    AsmMultArray(multiplier, arr1, 10);
    time(&endTime);

    cout<<"The time taken to run Assembly language procedure is: "<<long(endTime      - startTime)<< " seconds.";

    return 0;
}
```

**multarray.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"{
    //call to assembly language procedure
    void AsmMultArray(long multiplier, long arr1[], long count);

    //call to c++ language function
    void CMultArray(long multiplier, long arr1[], long count);

}
```

**.asm file**

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
TITLE MultArray Exmaple

; This program creates the procedure that multiplies the doubleword array by an
; Integer in both assembly and C++ languages and compares the execution times

.MODEL small
.data
AsmMultArray PROC USES edi eax ebx,
multiplier: DWORD, arrPtr: DWORD, count: DWORD

.code
mov edi, arrPtr
mov ebx, multiplier
mov ecx, count

L1:
mov eax,[edi]
mul ebx
mov [edi],eax
add edi,4
loop L1
ret

AsmMultArray ENDP
```

.

```
void CMultArray(long multiplier, long arr1[], long count)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            arr1[i]=arr1[i]*multiplier
        }
}
```

Comment: Just checking: the `CMultArray` function is not in the asm file, right? Also that has a missing semicolon.

Comment: The errors still occur after I added in the semicolon

Comment: You can't stick C code into the asm file...

Comment: removed C code. Unfortunately, I am still getting errors. Is there something missing at the end of my .asm file. Should there be something before or after ENDP AsmMultArray?

Comment: It might be picky about the missing `ENDS` directives to close your segments.

Comment: You've already removed the C code, or I'd point out the missing `;` after `multiplier`.  The assembler I use wants `end` on a line by itself at the end of the asm file.

Comment: At least three edits: Replace `.MODEL small`..`.data` by `.code`, add a `C`to `PROC` (`PROC C uses...`) and add an `END` at the end of the assembly file.

Comment: This question is not useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the *Irvine32* library by using `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc` the `model` is automatically set to `.MODEL small` so it can be safely removed from your code (and a warning will disappear).

Your assembler file has no global/static data so the `.data` section can be removed.

*PROC*s (functions) need to be placed into the `.code` section so `.code` must appear before the definition of the *PROC*. Failure to do so will confuse the assembler.

Since you will be calling your code from *C*/*C++*, you need to specify that your assembler code will use the *C* calling convention when it generates the appropriate prologue and epilogue code for the *PROC*. This includes setting up a stack frame and pushing/popping parameters, and accessing the arguments passed in the proper order. It also automatically prefixes your function name with an underscore. To do this you change the *PROC*'s definition to `PROC C USES` instead of `PROC USES` (Thanks @rkhb).

The end of the assembler file required an `END` as the last statement of the file.

Based on the suggestions above, your file should work if it was modified to look like this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
TITLE MultArray Example

; This program creates the procedure that multiplies the doubleword array by an
; Integer in both assembly and C++ languages and compares the execution times

.code
AsmMultArray PROC C USES edi eax ebx,
multiplier: DWORD, arrPtr: DWORD, count: DWORD

    mov edi, arrPtr
    mov ebx, multiplier
    mov ecx, count

L1:
    mov eax,[edi]
    mul ebx
    mov [edi],eax
    add edi,4
    loop L1
    ret

AsmMultArray ENDP
END
```